# Adding state to a @Stateless bean

Tags: java, ejb

I have some code in a bean that monitors a connection handle:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass { 
    private CloseableHttpAsyncClient deviceHandle = null;
    @Schedule(second="*/30", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)
    void checkConnection()
    {
        if (deviceHandle != null) {
            if (deviceHandle.isRunning()) {
                // Ping connection
            }
            else {
                deviceHandle = reconnectToDevice();
            }
        }
    }

    public void initialise() {
        deviceHandle = connectToDevice();
    }
}
```

According to the EJB 3.1 specs `@Schedule` may be used only on `@Stateless` beans, so of course my code fails because I get a different bean on the timer ticks with a null `deviceHandle`.

Therefore, my question is what is the best practise for this requirement - where should I stash my handle? `@Inject` a `@Singleton`? `@Inject` an `@ApplicationScoped` bean? `@Inject` the bean from my `ServletContextListener` and store the state there (I do that with another truly `@Stateless` timer tick)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to turn your `MyClass` itself into a `@Singleton`.

The EJB 3.1 spec does allow the use of `@Schedule` in singletons. Section 18.2.3 of the [spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) even contains the following example:

```
@Singleton
public class CacheBean {
    Cache cache;
    // Setup an automatic timer to refresh
    // the Singleton instance cache every 10 minutes
    @Schedule(minute=”*/10”, hour=”*”, persistent=false)
    public void refresh() {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Such a simple answer. I had tried just about every combination of annotations except for that one. `@javax.ejb.Singleton` isn't it, not `@javax.inject.Singleton`?

Comment: I've only done this with `@javax.ejb.singleton` so far.